# Scroll to reveal footer regardless of viewport height

Tags: scroll, responsive-design, footer

I'm trying to figure out how to code a footer exactly like this:

http://elevationchurch.org/

Basically, the footer isn't in view until you reach the bottom of the content.  So if you have a tall desktop browser that doesn't have a lot of content and the end of the content container is in view, the footer is still hidden, but you scroll down and the footer is revealed.

If you notice, scale your browser down to a more "mobile" size, and the footer is still "right-there" waiting to be revealed.

I feel like the answer is so easy, but I've scoured the code for javascript and css tricks, and I'm not seeing it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So checking via chrome's developer tools:

style.css has

```
html, .inspiration, .inspiration #outer, .inspiration #container, .inspiration #content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and if you enable/disable that css line, the content shrinks/expands as expected, so that's what's doing the magic.